# Qt/QML: Custom menu exceeding window boundaries

Tags: qt, menu, window, qml

I want to create a custom Qt/QML menu like the main menu in Firefox:

[image: Firefox menu]

As you can see, the menu can exceed the boundaries of the main window if it is bigger than the main window. Is there any way to achieve such behavior in Qt? I tried with the native `Menu` QML component, but this only gives me a default OS context menu with very vew customization options. I want full control over how the menu looks like and its contents (i.e. the same possibilities I have for a normal QML component or widget).

Comment: Just create a window, and in it put what ever you want? Seems quite straightforward.

Comment: Unclear what are you asking. What is "full control"? What is "can exceed the boundaries"? Please provide example.

Comment: Usually, a Qt Component is clipped by its parent window. This is not true for the menu in Firefox (see screenshot). I want to know how to achieve this in Qt.
By full control I mean that I can put into the container whatever components I want (just like I can put into a window whatever I want). When using native context menus, you are usually limited to the text for the menu entries and maybe an icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Qt Quick Controls 1](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-menu.html) has Menus that are native and hence are not limited to window bounds.
- [Qt Quick Controls 2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-menu.html) does not yet have support for native Menus. You can track that [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69558).
- [Qt Labs Platform](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qt-labs-platform-menu.html) has a native menu.

However, I doubt that any of these options will be sufficient in your case, as native menu support means utilising whatever the OS provides, which is probably not flexible enough to implement the menu shown in the image.

As mentioned by @hyde, one option may be to create a [Window](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html) and implement your menu in there.

Comment: Oh, so this means that context menus are basically frameless windows? I have already come up with this approach, but it didn't feel right.